# Paste whole column from a Workbook to a local column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import one value from many XML files, actually I can read the XML file and copy the data from the column "AK" but I'am having errors when I try to paste it from the Workbooks.

It would be perfect if I can add the content of each file at the bottom of the column at each file loop.

Here's my code :

```
xCount = 1
xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml")
desiredSheetName = Application.InputBox("Select any cell inside the target sheet: ", "Prompt for selecting target sheet name", Type:=8).Worksheet.Name
Do While xFile <> ""
    Set xWb = Workbooks.OpenXML(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)

    'problemes when I try to paste the data
    xWb.Sheets(1).Columns("AK:AK").Copy Worksheets(desiredSheetName).Cells(xCount, 1)
                   
    xWb.Close False
    xCount = desiredSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2
    xFile = Dir()
Loop
```

**Edit 1 :**
Note that I hardcoded the name of the desired sheetname "Feuil2", it started giving me selection problems with the new code.

I'm still having a message error : **The index does not belong to the selection.**

```
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml")
'desiredSheetName = Application.InputBox("Select any cell inside the target sheet: ", "Prompt for selecting target sheet name", Type:=8).Worksheet.Name

Do While xFile <> ""
    Set xWb = Workbooks.OpenXML(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
    
    xCount = Worksheets("Feuil2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print xCount
    
    xWb.Sheets(1).Columns("AK:AK").Copy Worksheets("Feuil2").Cells(xCount, 1)
            
    xWb.Close False
    xFile = Dir()
Loop
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Either `desiredSheetName` is a worksheet, like in `desiredSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` or it is the _name_ of a worksheet, like in `Worksheets(desiredSheetName)` - but your are using the same variable in both scenarios.  As the error occurs with `Worksheets(desiredSheetName)` I assume `desiredSheetName.cells(` will throw no error.

Comment: Try calculating `xCount` before `Worksheets(desiredSheetName).Cells(xCount, 1)` as  `xCount = Worksheets(desiredSheetName).Cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlUp).row`. And, of course, `Worksheets(desiredSheetName)` should be `Set`. Preferably before the loop... At least `desiredSheetName` String.

Comment: @Ike `desiredSheetName` is inputBox that ask the user the sheet where to paste the data, I updated the code with the `desiredSheetName` initialisation

Comment: Ok - then there are two errors in your code: set xCount as FaneDuru suggests _before_ you copy the value (otherwise xcount = 0 when the loop runs the first time which results in the error as there is no row 0) and use xCount = Worksheets(desiredSheetName)

Comment: Did you read my comment? Using `xCount = 1` all the time it will paste in "A1" overwriting the previous file data. `xCount = desiredSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2` is not the most elegant way, but what problem does your code have now? Did you test it?

Comment: `xCount = desiredSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2` is not the most appropriate because, in case of having first 10 rows empty, the above way will return wrong. And the recommended one, will correctly return in all circumstances.

Comment: I did the changes that you guys proposed (see Edit section), but I'm still having the error message : The index does not belong to the selection, I also hardcoded the sheetname because it starded having selection problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code mixes implicit and explict references:

`xWb.Sheets(1).Columns("AK:AK").Copy Worksheets("Feuil2").Cells(xCount, 1)`

`Worksheets("Feuil2")` references implicitly the *active* workbook which is the xWb which you opened before - I assume xWb lacks a Feuil2 - hence the index error.

Same with `xCount = Worksheets("Feuil2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` - `Rows.Count` will return the result from the *active* sheet which might be "Feuil1" when opening the workbook.

Furhtermore I think it helps to use well named variables - at least it would then be easier to spot errors.

Try this one:

```vb
Sub copyValuesFromFiles(xStrPath As String)

Dim wbTarget As Workbook, wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet

Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("Feuil2")

Dim firstEmptyRow As Long, cntSourceRows As Long

Dim xFile As String
xFile = Dir(xStrPath)   'adjust to your needs

Do While xFile <> ""
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.OpenXML(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets(1)
    
    With wsTarget
        firstEmptyRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 '+ 1 because you want to write to the first empty row
    End With
    
    With wsSource.Columns("AK:AK")
        cntSourceRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    With wsTarget.Cells(firstEmptyRow, 1)
        .Resize(cntSourceRows, 1).Value2 = wsSource.Columns("AK").Resize(cntSourceRows, 1).value2
    End With
            
    wbSource.Close False
    xFile = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i did implement your code now I have a popup error  `error 1004 You cannot paste this item here because the Copy and Paste areas are different in size.
• Select a single cell in the paste area or an area of the same size, and then try pasting again. `
For information one xml file can contain 500 values in the AK column

Comment: I took the copy-part from your code ... and didn't check it - sorry. I updated the code - now it's using direct writing to the target sheet - which is faster then copying the whole column.

Comment: Now it looks like it's doing all loops not like before it ended at the first file, but at the end it doesn't write in the sheet, just a question why did you choose `columns("K")` at the last `With` statement, did you mean A ?

Comment: Sorry - I put the K for testing ... adjusted the code. But I didn't understand what is not working?

Comment: No problem at all,.
The problem It doesn't print the data in the sheet, is the `Value2` in the last 'with' statement correct ?

Comment: Thanks man, I corrected it by changing the line in the last with statement to this
`.Resize(cntSourceRows, 1).Value = wsSource.Columns("AK").Resize(cntSourceRows, 1).Value`
I think you forgot the Value on the right side, update your answer and I'll accept it. thanks again ^^

Comment: code is corrected - sorry